# How to limit a number to a range

Tags: java, math

I have this function to limit a rotation to the range from 0.0 to 360.0:

```
private float ClampRotation( float rotation ) {

    while( rotation < 0.0f ) rotation += 360.0f;
    while( rotation >= 360.0f ) rotation -= 360.0f;

    return rotation;

}
```

This functions works great and it probably can't be more efficient, but I'm just wondering if there are a native Java function that can do the same?

The closest I get is Math.min/max, but it doesn't work as this.  A rotation of -10.0 should output 350.0 and not 0.0 as min/max would do.

Comment: It's certainly not the most efficient solution - the larger the number, the longer you loop.

Comment: "Can't be more efficient" it can be enormously more efficient for large values of rotation, as @Paul answer proves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

% (modulus) works on floating point values  so use `rotation % 360.0f` (you will need to add 360.0 afterwards to negative numbers)

Comment: The modulus operator just checks whether two numbers are evenly divisible... I'm not sure how it's going to help with the OP's question.

Comment: @willell: in fact, it returns the *remainder* when one number is divided by the other - when this is zero, they're exactly divisible.

Answer (score 4):

Use the modulus operator then account for values less than 0;

```
private float ClampRotation( float rotation ) {

    rotation = rotation % 360f;

    if (rotation < 0f) rotation += 360f;

    return rotation;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

it's just math.. you can do it like this:

```
private float ClampRotation( float rotation ) {

    return rotation+360.0f*Math.ceil(-rotation/360.0f);

}
```

i'm pretty sure it's ok

Comment: I think you just invented the `%` operator ;)

Comment: it's actually the opposite (finding how many times 'rotation' is in 360. modulo finds the remainder)
(btw - you still right when you're saying that it can be done with % instead. for some reason i prefer this..)

Comment: No, this is a variant of "floored division" modulo (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Nothing wrong with it - it worked for Knuth!

Answer (score 1):

You have the traditional implementation of wrapping angles which are less than an order of magnitude away the desired range.

Modulus is a bit weird for floating point - it returns negative for negative, so you still have to have a branch, and it involves a division, which is slower on some machines ( as in I've not found a machine where % is significantly less expensive than going round a loop with a couple of subtractions two or three times ).

If your values are within say -1000 to +1000, then your version is both clearer and faster. If your values are wider than that, go for a modulus based version. If it's very important, test both on your hardware with the value ranges you are going to use.